# how to disappear `BottomNavigationView` in some fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments, bottomnavigationview

I have a `BottomNavigationBar` in the MainActivity. I want to hide it in the some fragments.I saw this question but its solutions didn't work for me.[How to hide bottom navigation bar in specific fragment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50663874/how-to-hide-bottom-navigation-bar-in-specific-fragment)

I have three items with the following names.`MainPageFragment` and `ListQuestionFragment` and `ListAnswerQuestion`.`ListQuestionFragment` and `ListAnswerQuestion` contain the list of items and when User click every item a new fragment will be replaced.These fragments are the details of those item. I want to hide `BottomNavigationBar` in these fragments.

Comment: Get a reference to BottomNavigationBar view, and change the visibility to gone when you opening specific fragments.

Comment: Write these lines in onCreateView method of my fragment.But when I press back button in other fragments, it is gone.  BottomNavigationView view=getActivity().findViewById(R.id.bottom_nav);
        view.setVisibility(View.GONE);

Comment: When you clicking back you need to set the visibility back to visible if you want that it will be visible.

Comment: should I use an interface for implement onBackpress in fragment? I load my fragment this way: FragmentManager manager =((FragmentActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager();
                    manager.beginTransaction().addToBackStack(null).replace(R.id.flContent, detailAnswerFragment).commit();

Comment: I think all the logic for hiding and un-hiding  of  BottomNavigationBar should be done in activity, when you open different fragments you open them from activity so you know when to hide the BottomNavigationBar , and when you pressing back, handle the logic for un-hiding inside onBackPressed

Comment: Yes. I did it. thanks a lot